# Firebase username email and password registration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my registration code and I do not know how to separate this two functions. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
*operation=ValidateAuthServiceOperation java.lang.NullPointerException: onPostInitComplete can be called only once per call to getRemoteService
```

---

```
private void registerUser() {


//getting email and password from edit texts
final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

//checking if email and passwords are empty
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}

//if the email and password are not empty
//displaying a progress dialog




registerProgressDIg.setMessage("Registering Please Wait...");
registerProgressDIg.show();



// Register the user

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());


        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            final ArrayList<String> defaultRoom = new ArrayList<String>();
            defaultRoom.add("home");

            // Update the user profile information
            final FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(String.valueOf(displayUsername))
                    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"))
                    .build();
            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "User profile updated.");
                        // Construct the ChatUser
                        UserList.user = new ChatUser(user.getUid(),displayUsername, editTextEmail,true,defaultRoom);
                        // Setup link to users database
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).setValue(UserList.user);
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserList.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        else {

            Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, "createUserWithEmailAndPassword", task.getException());
            Utils.showDialog(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.err_singup));


        }

    }
});
}
```

Anyone with an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you Enable SIGN-IN METHOD for email and password in Authentication in Firebase Concole?.Try this will help you.

Comment: @FirdoshAnsari yes it is enabled..it was working very well when i had the email and password registration alone but now when i add a username,

Comment: I think it's not possible in Firebase Authentication because it provides only two field Email and Password in Authentication so I think it's not possible to add third field (i.e Username)

Comment: There's a lot more due diligence you could do here. Have you, for instance, verified that the profile is actually updated inside the onComplete listener, and that the values of `email` and `password` are in fact what you expect (and that those point to a valid account)? I recall a bug with cached profiles not updating until logging out and back in. Include relevant code, sample data, debug logging, and version info for debug help. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SirGeorge did you solve your issue yet?, I'm having it too :(

Comment: u guys either do not understand the question or cant admit that you do not know how to!!!!! its very possible to update user profile, only that i have messed up somewhere in my code

Comment: i faced this issue twice and both happened after making sure the code is working..i did solve it by replacing json file,reEnabling email signup from SignUp-Methods(second time),first time(i just waited for 24 hours,don't know why) hope it helps.